# Connect landline phone to computer for attending a call

Tags: java, networking, phone-call

I want to connect my land-line phone to computer and attend calls from computer. I want to create an application for this. This application will be able to attend an incoming call and create a new call.
Can it be done in java? any one give me some idea about this.

Comment: any body knows how to use java.telephony api